# Skype crashes every 3 mins since upgrading to win10

Tags: windows-10, crash, skype

I had Windows 8.1 and Skype 7.17 and upgraded to Windows 10. Since then, Skype crashes every 5-10 minutes (some days not at all on other days 5-10 minutes max, then it crashes).

I've updated to the newest Skype version in attempt to rule out an old version, but this doesn't work.

From what I'm seeing 2 different `.dll`'s are mentioned in the crash entry of the event logs:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll
```

Is there anything known about this and how to correct this?

Comment: Are there any error messages? Anything in the [event logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: good point. no error message.  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll and  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll mentioned in the last few error messages in the event logs

Comment: Please [edit] and include the details from those 2 events.

Comment: allready on to it only searched through the logs some more before that

Comment: Check the application event log as well. Skype might stick something in there.

Comment: That is directly from thae application event logs. Aside from that I didnt see anything skype related int here. Only that the skype service gets started again by me.

Comment: Try to stop any webserver service (IIS, wamp, xamp). Then RESET and try again. I have experienced that sometimes there is a collision trying to use some ports.

Comment: @josem As I dont have the problem any longer sadly I can't if it would work. (it stopped a few skype versions ago)

Answer (score -1):

Completely uninstall skype and redownload the installer and install skype.  Skype works fine for me on win 10.

http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/